# Image not aligning with text

Tags: block-editor

I have recently switched to using the Block Editor.

I am having a problem with the alignment of an image with the top of the text in the first paragraph block.

This is how it appears in the block editor:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/8ptg988u9gi23oj/Image1.jpg?dl=0

This is how it appears in preview:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/2ehv3rhfgad6ej9/Image2.jpg?dl=0

You can see that the top of the image is not aligned with the first line of text as it is in the editor.

I did not have this problem with the Classic Editor.

Any suggestions?

Thanks,

Martin.

Comment: This is likely due to a disparity in the CSS between the theme and the block editor - either in the theme not implementing default Gutenberg styles or not adjusting block editor styles to match the front-end. If you are not using a default theme(?) you will need to direct this question to the official support channels for the theme in question

Comment: Thank you for the information.  I am using one of the default themes (twenty ten).  Are themes supported separately from Wordpress?